# Crossdomain.xml on which server?

Tags: flash, crossdomain.xml

There's a SWF file/app on someone's server that accepts URLs that contain data. Normally the URLs are from the same origin, so when I use a file from my server I get the same origin policy error.

**On which server do I need to add/update the `crossdomain.xml` file?**

*It's probably the server I don't have access to, in that case, what are my other options?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crossdomain.xml file needs to be on the server where the data is being retrieved from.

In this case it sounds like you should deploy the crossdomain.xml to your server.

The crossdomain.xml basically says, "it's ok for SWF files from these domains to access the data on my server."